# printf("%m") reports an error yet errno is set to 0

Tags: c, sockets, libc, uclibc, getsockopt

I'm connecting to a TCP socket, nonblockingly.
`printf("%m")` prints out `Operation now in progress` yet `errno` is set to `0`. I save `errno`'s value before printing too, to make sure `printf` doesn't fiddle with it. It's weird - `printf` should output `Success`. I mean obviously the problem is that when I access `errno` I get `0`. I'm using uclibc on a pretty old kernel (Around 2.6), if that matters. I can't really find any difference between how `vsprintf` accesses `errno` vs me accessing `*__errno_location()`.

Alternatively, how could I tell if my socket had an actual issue with `connect` or if it's just still connecting?

Example:

```c
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_TCP);

/* create sockaddr struct (remote)... */

int fd = connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr*)&remote, sizeof(remote));

printf("%d, %d\n", fd, errno);
printf("%m");
```

Outputs:

```
-1, 0
Operation now in progress
```

I'd expect the following output:

```
-1, 115
Operation now in progress
```

As 115 is EINPROGRESS

Comment: What is the actual `errno`? What does `strerror(0)` return?

Comment: `errno` is 0, `strerror(0)` is `Success`

Comment: `Operation now in progress` corresponds to `EINPROGRESS`.

Comment: Yeah. I know. But when I check `errno`'s value I get `0`. I don't get `150` which is `EINPROGRESS`. Yet right after that `printf("%m")` outputs `Operation now in progress`. Which is the problem

Comment: Please show the code, preferable a [mre]. Otherwise we do not know how exactly `errno` is set or checked. Did you try to write `errno` and read `*__errno_location()` or vice versa?

Comment: Added an example. Hope it suffices

Comment: The code is flawed - `printf` may set errno to `115`, resulting in subsequent `printf` in printing the errno. It may also happen that `printf` happens to set errno to 115 before executing `%m`. Please maybe try `int fd = connect(...); int sav = errno; printf("%m %d %d\n", fd, errno);`. Please post an [MCVE] and if `%m` _extension_ is not working, then try the standard `strerror`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have indeed tried saving the value inbetween the `printf` and `connect`. It seems as if `%m` accesses a different `errno`. But from the research I've done - it should access the very same value, obviously.

Comment: Also - why would `printf` set errno to `EINPROGRESS`? I mean it _could_, but why would it

Comment: It might sound silly, but I'd verify that you don't have something shadowing `errno` in your scope (because that sounds to me like the most reasonable explanation). This could be anything from a macro to a difference between how your code and the library handle thread local storage (e.g. library built without threads configured, you're bulit with threads configured, or vice versa)

Comment: @Hasturkun Besides setting a watchpoint on errno's address with GDB, what else could I do?

Comment: A watchpoint probably won't help in this case, because it sounds like your errno and the library's aren't the same one. You can check a disassembly to see how you're getting at errno (or preprocessor output for some cases) and compare it to something from the library. Searching for "uclibc errno" brings up some bugs that sound related (e.g. [this](http://uclibc.10924.n7.nabble.com/PATCH-fix-errno-location-for-non-TLS-case-tp2684.html)). I don't know what uclibc version you're on, so don't know if you're affected by one of these.